# Ng2SearchPipeModule giving error filter not found

Tags: angular

I am using Ng2SearchPipeModule for filtersearch but its giving error like

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'filter' could not be found
```

I have imported and added module in import of my root module.

```
<input `matInput` type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="Enter Email id/User Name/User id">
              {{searchText}}
                <div *ngFor = "let u of users1 | filter:searchText">
                  {{u}}
                </div>`
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You have to import Ng2pipeModule in app.module.ts file or in any parent module file as

```
import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from 'ng2-search-filter';
```

also add in imports array as:

```
  imports: [Ng2SearchPipeModule]
```

Comment: yes i did this in app.module.ts. 
Other than app.module i have 3 more module and in shared module i am using this filter.

Comment: are you importing the share module in the same module where component is declared?

Comment: yes.All other services are also declared in the same module. those are accessible.
But since ng2SearchPipe is readymade module i am importing it in app.module.ts and using in one feature module.